# Why does max() return an empty list as the largest item (larger than integers)

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, max

Why is an empty list deemed larger than integers:

```
In [112]: max(1,2,[])
Out[112]:[]
```

yet smaller than a string:

```
In [112]: max(1,'a',[])
Out[112]:'a'
```

Comment: Because `[] > 10` and `'a' > []`

Comment: Right. My questions then become: why is `[] > 10` and why is `'a' > []`

Comment: Because Guido said so (lists are bigger than ints, and strings are bigger than both). Interestingly, they become uncomparable in python3